# behaviour difference between list() function and [] in a conditional, the former behaves like string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does list(str) behaves as string here when [str] doesn't?

Is there a difference between these methods

[image]

Before someone marks this as a duplicate do link the answer because I've spent a fair bit of time scrawling through stackoverflow!

code

```py
x = 'ar'
'a' in list(x)
#True
'a' in [x]
#False
l = list(x)
'a' in l
#True
type(list(x))
#list
type([x])
#list
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image. I'd like to answer you, but I don't want to type your code myself when I could copy that.

Comment: Good point, added

Comment: Try printing `list(x)`, `[x]`, and `l`. What are their values?

Comment: oh, the former splits each character into it's own list element... should've spotted that

Comment: `list(x)= ["a","r"]` so `"a"` is clearly in it .... `[x] == ["ar"]` so `'a'` clearly not in it ... could have easily found that out by simply printing

Comment: Yeah cheers as I said, should've spotted that

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Why not simply test `'a' in x`?

Comment: I have a conditional to check if `'a' in x:` but x can be both a list[str] or just a string, so at the moment I check if x is a str and re-assign it as [x] so the conditional still works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `list()` converts the string to a list where each letter is one element. But `[]` creates a list where the things inside are the elements. `List()` is converting the string to a list whereas `[]` is just putting the string in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use debug output for clarifying such things. Like this:

```py
x = 'ar'
print(list(x))
print([x])
```

Prints this:

```
['a', 'r']
['ar']
```

Then let's think logically. `list(x)` is a constructor of a list from the string, it creates a list of all characters of a given string. And `[x]` just creates a list with one item: `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are asking if the element 'a' is in the list. Which it is not, your only element is 'ar'. If you `print([x])` the result should be `['ar']`

Answer (score 0):

`[x]` creates a single-element list, where the element is x. So if `x = 'ar'`, then the resulting list is `['ar']`.

`list(x)` casts the variable `x` into a list. This can work on any iterable object, and strings are iterable. The resulting list is `['a', 'r']`.

The element `'a'` is in the second list but not the first.